# Expoting MySQL data to Excel file

Tags: html, excel

I want to download an Excel file from a MySQL database query.

This is the code I am using;

```
<?php
include '../database.php';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle and JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <title>Capenergy Explotación de datos</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <H1>Explotación de datos </H1>
                <H2>Inneoterapia DESPI</H2>
                <H3>Post market follow up</H3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Post market follow up - Inneoterapia DESPI</h2>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Profesional</th>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Fecha consulta</th>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Código consulta</th>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Sexo</th>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Edad</th>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Motivo consulta</th>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Número de sesiones</th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php

                        $myquery = "SELECT 
                        profesional.nombre as nombre_profesional,
                        profesional.apellidos as apellidos_profesional,
                        consulta.fecha as fecha_consulta,
                        consulta.codigo as codigo_consulta,
                        paciente.sexo as sexo_paciente,
                        paciente.edad as edad_paciente,
                        consulta.motivo1 as motivo_consulta1,
                        consulta.motivo2 as motivo_consulta2,
                        consulta.motivo3 as motivo_consulta3,
                        consulta.motivo4 as motivo_consulta4,
                        consulta.motivo5 as motivo_consulta5,
                        (SELECT MAX(numero_sesion) FROM tb_sesiones_2022 WHERE tb_sesiones_2022.codigo_consulta = consulta.codigo) as numero_sesiones
                        FROM tb_consultas consulta
                        LEFT JOIN users profesional ON consulta.profesional = profesional.id
                        LEFT JOIN tb_pacientes paciente ON consulta.paciente = paciente.id_paciente
                        WHERE consulta.clinica = 11";

                        $my_res = mysqli_query($con,$myquery);

                        while($my_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($my_res))
                        {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['apellidos_profesional'].', '.$my_data['nombre_profesional'];?></td>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['fecha_consulta'];?></td>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['codigo_consulta'];?></td>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['sexo_paciente'];?></td>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['edad_paciente'];?></td>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['motivo_consulta1'].", ".$my_data['motivo_consulta2'].", ".$my_data['motivo_consulta3'].", ".$my_data['motivo_consulta4'].", ".$my_data['motivo_consulta5'];?></td>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['numero_sesiones'];?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php    
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="postmarketfollowup_export.php" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Exportar a Excel</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here you have the code for `postmarketfollowup_export.php`

```
<?php
include '../database.php';

header('Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel');
$filename = "postmarketfollowup_despi.xls";
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=\"$filename\"");  

?>
<table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Profesional</th>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Fecha consulta</th>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Código consulta</th>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Sexo</th>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Edad</th>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Motivo consulta</th>
                            <th style="border: 2px solid black">Número de sesiones</th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php

                        $myquery = "SELECT 
                        profesional.nombre as nombre_profesional,
                        profesional.apellidos as apellidos_profesional,
                        consulta.fecha as fecha_consulta,
                        consulta.codigo as codigo_consulta,
                        paciente.sexo as sexo_paciente,
                        paciente.edad as edad_paciente,
                        consulta.motivo1 as motivo_consulta1,
                        consulta.motivo2 as motivo_consulta2,
                        consulta.motivo3 as motivo_consulta3,
                        consulta.motivo4 as motivo_consulta4,
                        consulta.motivo5 as motivo_consulta5,
                        (SELECT MAX(numero_sesion) FROM tb_sesiones_2022 WHERE tb_sesiones_2022.codigo_consulta = consulta.codigo) as numero_sesiones
                        FROM tb_consultas consulta
                        LEFT JOIN users profesional ON consulta.profesional = profesional.id
                        LEFT JOIN tb_pacientes paciente ON consulta.paciente = paciente.id_paciente
                        WHERE consulta.clinica = 11";

                        $my_res = mysqli_query($con,$myquery);

                        while($my_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($my_res))
                        {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['apellidos_profesional'].', '.$my_data['nombre_profesional'];?></td>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['fecha_consulta'];?></td>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['codigo_consulta'];?></td>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['sexo_paciente'];?></td>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['edad_paciente'];?></td>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['motivo_consulta1'].", ".$my_data['motivo_consulta2'].", ".$my_data['motivo_consulta3'].", ".$my_data['motivo_consulta4'].", ".$my_data['motivo_consulta5'];?></td>
                                <td style="border: 2px solid black"><?php echo $my_data['numero_sesiones'];?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php    
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="postmarketfollowup_export.php" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Exportar a Excel</a>

                </div>
```

The web output is fine:

[image]

But the Excel file output is not so fine:

[image]

I guess there should be something wrong with the html bootstrap tags.
I would like to get the Excel file output like the web output.

Comment: Excel did not open the html file as html, it opened it as a text file. This may be a setting on the excel side as opposed to a programming problem.

Comment: @Shadow, may be the issue that I am opening the file in a Mac with the Numbers app and not with Excel?

Comment: I'm not sure how exporting as an html table is expected to become an excel file. See this tutorial for exporting to excel : https://www.codexworld.com/export-data-to-excel-in-php/

Comment: @Kendle, I think I am using the same procedure as in your attached tutorial

Comment: @mvasco Well, the numbers app is not excel, is it? The file you generated is **not** an excel file. Excel can interpret html pages, tables in particular, but you have to check if the numbers app can do the same.

Comment: @Shadow, I have opened the downloaded file using Excel online, and it is shown as I expected, thank you for your time and effort

Answer (score 0):

try

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Without a Content-type it is being opened as plain text.

Your line has vnd- not vnd.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The 4th line in the export php code in the question is `header('Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel');`

Comment: Your line has vnd- not vnd.

Comment: If you read the OP's comment below the question, this is not an issue. When he opened the file in Excel, it worked.

Comment: I did read the OPs comments.  It opens from a downloaded file because the OS recognizes the ".xls" file extension.  He has the wrong content-type which is why it is opening up as text directly from the browser.

Comment: @Shadow, please change your vote.  His content-type is application/vnd-ms-excel not application/vnd.ms-excel.  This is 100% the reason that his page gets loaded as text.